How to insert a date field in a string query field?
In my batch class, I have a string query field which has to get a dateTime field in the WHERE clause. I am using dateTime.format() but getting the error:
System.QueryException: unexpected token: '/'

Below is my code:
public class BatchTestClone implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    public DateTime testDate;
    public String status;
    public BatchTestClone(DateTime testDate, String status) {
        this.testDate = testDate;
        this.status= status;
    }
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        
        String query = 'SELECT Id FROM ServiceAppointment ';
        query += ' WHERE testDate__c > '+  testDate.format()  +' AND SchedEndTime < TODAY ';
        system.debug(Database.getQueryLocator(query));
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

I am calling this batch class like below:
DateTime testDate = DateTime.newInstance(2023,1,1,0,0,0);
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new BatchRiskAssessmentClone(testDate ,'To Be Worked'), 200);

The error is because the testDate has the format '1/1/2023 12:00 AM'. How to resolve this?
UPDATE:
Tried using testDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a')
Value of this is: 2023-01-01 12:00 AM
Now getting error: System.QueryException: unexpected token: '12'

As pointed out in the question linked by NickC, you should bind that variable: WHERE testDate__c > :testDate

Try using the format option with timezone specified:
DateTime testDate = DateTime.newInstance(2023,1,1,0,0,0);

// Format DateTime to string for use in SOQL query
String formattedDate = testDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');

System.debug('This is the formatted date required : '+formattedDate);
String query = 'SELECT Id FROM ServiceAppointment ';
        query += ' WHERE testDate__c > '+  formattedDate +' AND SchedEndTime < TODAY ';
        system.debug(Database.getQueryLocator(query));
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

